# JavaScript needs to only be called on button click in Rails project

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

i am unable to make my JavaScript code work as intended. The script should run only the click of the button, but it is running even when page refreshes.

```
- if params[:id] == "HuckabeeBook"
  :javascript
    function LoadScript(url) {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.setAttribute('src', url);
      script.setAttribute('async', false);
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
    $(function () {
      $('#submit_contribution.donate-btn').click(function () {
        LoadScript('https://secure.adnxs.com/px?id=1585351&seg=30062567&t=1');
      });
    });
```

I think i am missing out something here, any would be appreciated. Cheers

Comment: My testing approach is Ctrl + u to check the source code. I am not well versed with JavaScript and would like to know if there is a better way to test this

Comment: May be try `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` instead `$(function () {});`